# Application intro once logged in by Facebook how to skip intro next time?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, uiscrollview

I'm building an app that starts with a UIScrollView with 3 information images on how to use the app it then opens a Facebook login screen on the 3rd screen, once your logged in the app opens up... If the app is closed it restarts with the UIScrollView again!

Is there a way of skipping this once you've been logged in with Facebook?

Any advice on this please.

Comment: I don't understand your question very well. But, do you want to save the fact that the user is logged in with facebook and update your view controller that has the istance of UIScrollView class?

Comment: Once logged in to facebook and you close the app on your phone and re-open it, it always starts with the uiscrollview but I want it to just start on the main view controller, does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you login through Facebook store an object for key `kFirstTimeLogIn` in the `NSUserDefaults` like this....

```
NSString *value = @"NO";
NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userPreferences setObject:value forKey:@"kFirstTimeLogIn"];
[userPreferences synchronize];
```

so when every time your app launches check for this key and if this results a nil value than show the scrollview else by pass the scroll view.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, where would this code go in my app? I'm still fairly new to coding but getting there.

Comment: if you are using the Facebook sdk then you can write it inside the delegate method fbDidLogin.

Comment: I thought the fbDidLogin was in the header Facebook.h which is now a deprecated header? Will check again. Thanks